# Running bat files in Jenkins

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I have a simple question.  I want to run a bat file that should run post build.  The bat file takes in to parameters previousVersion and currentVersion (These parameters are entered as Validating String Parameters before the build starts).

This is what I have tried
Execute Windows Batch Command

```
set v = %currentVersion%
set pv = %previousVersion%
cmd \k "C:\jenkins\workspace\mybatfile.bat %pv% %p%"
```

The error I get is that cmd is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file exit 9009

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Replace "cmd \k" with "call"

The Execute Windows Batch command is running inside a cmd already; no need to specifically start a new one.  Just "call" your BAT file.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooo much. Wish you could help me with my dotopenauth problem

Comment: it's really helpful, not sure why in some jobs we can use CMD to run ,but in some jobs it cannot. anyway after remove the CMD /C and use the 'call' ,it worked now ,thanks .

Answer (score 0):

if you want to start a separate Command window you can try:

```
start cmd \k "your\bat"
```

here is a reference: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do like this, first point it to the path where your bat file exists, and then 'call' command to trigger that bat file. As below:

```
cd yourFilePath
```

and then

```
call yourFile.bat
```

Answer (score -1):

Create file name `jenkins.bat` and place this file where your `jenkins.war` file is available.

You have to click `jenkins.bat` file.

Note :- After click on `jenkins.bat` file, chrome browser will automatically open with jenkins url.

> Try this If your system configured with Java 8 or 7 Installation.

```
timeout 3
start chrome http://localhost:8080
timeout 3
java -jar jenkins.war
```

> Try this If your system configured with Java 10 or above Installation.

```
timeout 3
start chrome http://localhost:8080
timeout 3
java -jar jenkins.war --enable-future-java
```

Comment: Have you try this answer?