# Jenkins ssh from Linux server to a Windows node

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Linux is the operating system for my Jenkins server. How to configure a job to run a .bat script on a windows node?  Is this even possible to go cross platform like that?

Answer (score 1):

We have Ubuntu Jenkins server that runs jobs on Windows slave nodes. We had a Windows Jenkins server and we use the same jobs, without modification, running on the Ubuntu master. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020945/executing-batch-file-in-jenkins) or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228327/running-bat-files-in-jenkins) could be helpful.

We connect Windows nodes to the Ubuntu master the same way we connected them to the Windows master.  For more info about connecting nodes see [this article](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows).